# .htaccess allow IP from MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, .htaccess, ip

I know that with `.htaccess` you can add access users by usin MySQL database to try and authenticate users.

https://helpdesk.islandnet.com/help/htaccess.php#mysql

But I want to add that `.htaccess` looks at the MySQL database and only allows IP addresses which are stored in that database.

It is impossible? If not, how?

Comment: I do not think the feature is built in, could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think AuthMySQL does not allow anything without password authentication.

Horewer, you can achieve what you want by doing it in horribly wrong way.

You could write cron script which:

1. loads allowed IP list from database
2. generates .htaccess file based on these IPs
3. replaces old .htacess with new one